# error_log passing parameter to sender

Tags: php, email, debugging, error-handling

When I use function [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) with `$message_type = 1` - sent by email, I need to pass to sendmail extra parameter `"-f" . $sendermail`

Is there way which I can pass parameter to sender, same way as it can be done with [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and `$additional_parameters`?

Documentation says

> This message type uses the same internal function as mail() does.

But I can't see quick way how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as a "quick" way to do it is concerned, presuming you mean passing extra arguments or the like, then no. Take a look at the [source code for `error_log`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5595dd5ffa3453f22c0508052417d3b2853f5015/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4678-4682), noticing that `NULL` is passed explicitly to the parameter in question for the `mail` function:

```
if (!php_mail(opt, "PHP error_log message", message, headers, NULL)) {
```

Other than using `set_error_handler` as others have mentioned, you could try using the runtime configuration `mail.force_extra_parameters` ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.force_extra_parameters)).

> Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.

I have used this before, with the caveat of it overriding options elsewhere so you may have to consider whether it's beneficial to you. For instance, this is what I use in a `.conf` include on my apache dev server:

```
# force envelope sender and name and in turn ignore any passed in to PHP mail() function
php_admin_value mail.force_extra_parameters "-f leonard@mydevserver.co.uk -F \"Development: leonard\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the PHP Source the `error_log` functions invokes `php_mail` and sends a `NULL` value for this argument.

```
    case 1:     /*send an email */
        if (!php_mail(opt, "PHP error_log message", message, headers, NULL)) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        break;
```

(Source: [php-src/ext/standard/basic_functions.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5595dd5ffa3453f22c0508052417d3b2853f5015/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4679))

You have to stick to a [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and write your own error handler.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try `error_log` with message_type 1, but i know how works `mail`, so i guess you have to try something like:

```
$headers = "From: $name <{$email}>\r\n".
           "Reply-To: {$email}\r\n";
error_log('Foo', 1, 'bar@php.com', $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use error_log_handler as seen http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
mixed set_error_handler ( callable $error_handler [, int $error_types = E_ALL | E_STRICT ] )
```

to set a function to handle errors in a script. I believe this is the standard way to add functions to error_logs.